# How do I get auxiliary routes from url using Angular2's functionality?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this url which is generated by navigating to two auxiliary routes (`foo` and `bar`) which are **children** of `page` route:

`localhost:4200/page/(tab1:foo//tab2:bar)`

`tab1` and `tab2` are names of router outlets.

How do I get these two routes - `foo` and `bar` - as a string using Angular2's functionality?

Let's assume that everything is configured properly.

My current solution is using `Router`'s `url` property with regular expressions which feels a bit "hacky" considering how vast Angular2's possibilities are.

Comment: how do you mean get it? like you want to navigate there? or you want to just console.log what route you are on? you want to call your route in a function? what do you mean my friend? :)

Comment: I need to get `foo` and `bar` string from the url. I'm aware that I can use `router.url` property and just cut the string but is there more 'Angularish' way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a optional param named :expression and get the parameter then parse it.

I provided a simple plunk for you: https://embed.plnkr.co/IPFX7gnCYN9OQJ5DFBVi/

**UPDATE:**

with auxiliary routes: https://embed.plnkr.co/dVTPhJtrXjKDVPliE5qv/

you should inject ActivatedRoute to the main route that contains  then you can get foo & bar by below code :

```
let children = this._route.snapshot.children,    

children.forEach(child => console.log((child.url[0] || {path:''}).path);
// ''
// foo
// bar
```

hope help u.

Comment: Thank you but your example is not solving the problem because in your case we're getting a string as a param which makes it unrelated to usage of auxiliary routes in Angular2.